# How to add URL to a Generic ListView

Tags: django

I was trying to add a link to my ListView so it can display the detail view when user click on it but it is telling me My Object is not iterable

Comment: Show your codes. Else, we can't answer properly.

Comment: You need to mention your current implementation. Firstly you need to be sure that it display data in listview in template.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure you read [ask] and then check how to write a [mcve] to learn how to best make use of the SO community.

Answer (score -2):

It expects a queryset with a dictionary of values, instead of the individual item.

Try using queries like all, filter etc.

```
model.objects.all()
```

which returns a queryset.

Comment: Hi @sumit, welcome to SO. Please don't answer questions that aren't clearly formulated. You probably wanted to comment, which you can't until you have enough reputation, but still, try to find other questions for which you do have an answer.